# In CRM 2011 Advanced find is there a way to add a date comparison option 'Older than X Days'

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dashboard

In CRM 2011 Advanced find is there a way to add a date comparison option 'Older than X Days'

There is and 'Older than X Months' but not Days.

I want 'Older than X Days' and 'Older than X Hours' would be good too.

Is there some api or table to add this to the drop down options.

---

> And I know its probably bad form to editorialize but WTF Microsoft!
> Why would you implement 'Older than X Months' and not Older than X
> Days. If you were in sales and waited 30 days before you found out
> something was aged you'd lose a customer.
>
> Now I'm probably going to
> have to write a Report and work out how to show it in an iframe to get
> this on a dashboard.

EDIT

On abs or rel. The way CRM does Older than X Months is how I would expect it to work. I am pretty sure in english it would read "this date is older than 1 month" I want "this date was more than 7 days ago" and nice to have would be "this time occurred more than 48hrs ago"

Comment: What would you like to express? Do you need a relative or absolute comparison? btw.: You should state your WTF there -> https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions

Comment: Actually it's already on Connect at number 17 on the "most voted" chart and you can vote for it too: https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedback/details/687024/add-older-than-x-days-in-date-criteria - it has been there just over a year now. Probably suggested too late for R8 but let's see if they make some helpful changes to the FetchXml spec to accomodate this for R10 (I think that's where the issue is, not in CRM per se but in the MS implementation / definition of FetchXml)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on where to vent :) 

See EDIT for more info 

and voted

Comment: Now a dead link. On the MSDN site. What a surprise.